# How to make node-waf build binaries with debug symbols?

Tags: node.js, build, g++, waf

Running node-waf with *--verbose* shows it uses g++ with *-g*. It seems to be default. I can't find an obvious way to tell node-waf to build node.js extensions without debug symbols. Is there a straight forward way?

*Edit:* I know how to add compiler options. The question would be how to remove a certain option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Not sure whether this is the best solution. Just overwriting the *CXXFLAGS* seems to do what I want.

```
import Options

def set_options(ctx):
  ctx.tool_options('compiler_cxx')
  ctx.add_option('--mode', action='store', default='release', help='Compile mode: release or debug')

def configure(ctx):
  ctx.check_tool('compiler_cxx')
  ctx.check_tool('node_addon')
  if Options.options.mode == 'release':
    ctx.env['CXXFLAGS'] = ['-O3']
```

Comment: How is this used from the command line? I just get `error: No such command 'debug'`

Comment: I think I just called `node-waf --mode debug`.